# Issues with node and npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed `nodejs` via `apt-get install nodejs`. Works fine.

When I try to install `socket.io` using `npm install --save socket.io` I end up with failures:

```
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
```

I have attempted to fix this using:

```
sudo update-alternative --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodesjs 10
```

... to no avail.

I tried to build `node` from source, but `npm` doesn't get installed - Docs say `npm` should be installed when building `node` from source.

I have downloaded the binaries from the node site and moved `node` and `npm` to `/usr/local/bin`. Node works fine when doing this, but `npm` doesn't. I always get `command not found` and when trying to run `npm` using the absolute path: `/usr/local/bin/npm` it's not found (permissions were correct).

If I run: `node -v` I get `v0.10.29` which is the same as running 'nodejs -v'.

So, I am left in the dark not knowing what to do next.

Any advice please?

Comment: Make sure you are using sudo. Can you add the whole error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the old version with:

```
apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
```

And try to install again.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
```

To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manually moved `npm` into `/usr/local/bin` you should write this command to your cli and try again.

```
alias npm="/usr/local/bin/npm"
```

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is in the `$PATH` would I still need to do this? Other software I've installed to the same directory do not require this.